# Ckeditor set values on dialog windows

Tags: ckeditor

i'm trying this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function imageurl() {

    var i = CKEDITOR.instances.myeditor1;


    i.editor.execCommand( 'image' );


var dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
dialog.setValueof('info','txtUrl',"myurl");

}
```

When i click the link, the image windows runs ok but i can´t set the desired values.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide more information? What have you tried? Are you seeing any errors? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Hi, I have not seen any error.
What I need is to insert the url of an image externally to CKEditor. I'm trying to do through dialogue image. Although otherwise I would be valid. The idea is as follows:

- The user creates a new entry
- In this new entry can upload as many pictures as he wants (separate table from an iframe)
- Then, with each image, and through a link, the user can go inserting the desired CKEditor.

On debugging, I have no idea how it's done

Comment: Fixed an easier way.
I used inserthtml.